# How do I raise a custom event using Channel Integration Framework in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: events, twilio, dynamics-crm, integration, twilio-flex

We have Twilio Flex running in a Channel Integration Framework (CIF) panel embedded in Dynamics CRM. Using CIF it is possible to interact with Dynamics CRM from Twilio Flex, and it is possible for Twilio Flex to listen for CIF events coming out of Dynamics CRM.

For instance, the standard phone number field button on CRM raises an 'onclicktoact' CIF event through the framework, which can be captured in the Flex panel to start outbound calls in Twilio Flex.

However, during a call in Twilio, we require to update the call context in Twilio with information coming out of CRM - e.g. the CRM ID of a new record being created, or details on changes to an existing record.

How do I raise a custom 'onclicktoact' event in Dynamics CRM through CIF to make Twilio aware of changes happening in Dynamics CRM? Is it possible to raise such an event in JavaScript on a button in the ribbon within Dynamics CRM?

Comment: any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is, create a PCF control to include a custom textbox + phone icon button similar to OOB phone field control and implement the CRM context aware click-to-dial to CIF panel.

I am aware, that is how Solgari (a Microsoft CIF partner) implemented it. [Read more](https://solgari.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026488154-How-to-Enable-Click-to-Dial-through-CIF)